# How to supply an op-amp from a 9V Battery?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, amplifier

I was buildiing an amplifier circuit for +ve voltages only. When I used a 9V battery to supply V+ and V- (+ to V+, - to V-), I get a constant 8V at the output of the opamp. The output is not changing with respect to input. The circuit worked fine when I used a +/-12V dual power supply. However the way I understand it, using a single supply is okay as long as I'm not dealing with negative input voltages.

Comment: Choose to have both inputs near V+/2 and expect DC to Vout=V+/2 , you may have to AC couple unless you can define here

Comment: What op amp are you using?

Comment: You mean +/-12V. I tried dividing a 9V battery to make a dual supply, but when I connect it to the opamp, I get different voltages at + and - terminals.

Comment: @C_Elegans LM741

Comment: Can you simply use two 9V batteries to provide +9 and -9 volts to the opamp power pins?

Comment: Can you show us the schematic for the amplifier that worked with \$\pm\:12\:\text{V}\$? It would go a long way in helping you, I think. There are different approaches to getting something working on a single \$9\:\text{V}\$ supply (with \$1-2\:\Omega\$ series impedance.)

Comment: You could consider a [discrete rail splitter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/348485/is-there-a-good-topology-for-splitting-a-dc-power-supply-from-a-few-lm2576-and-l/348506#348506). It's not designed for an 9 V battery. But at least you can see the complexity involved. You really need to specify the current compliance you need.

Comment: [Reasons not to use a 741](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp/304522#304522)

Answer (score 1):

According to page 4 of the [LM741 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm741.pdf), the minimum supply voltage is +/- 10V, so powering it with +/-9V isn't guaranteed to work. The LM741 is a very old design, and its characteristics are not as good as modern op amps (that being said, it works fine, but it's not what I'd pick for a new design). I'd recommend getting a more modern op amp, you probably want one with rail to rail inputs and outputs as well as a lower minimum supply voltage. I've narrowed down the listing [here](https://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Integrated-Circuits-ICs/Amplifier-ICs/Operational-Amplifiers-Op-Amps/_/N-6j73m?P=1z0z63x&Rl=6j73mZgjdhplZ1yvm6nqZ1yvm31nSGT6j73mZgjdhk9Z1yzml8wZ1yzmm0eSGT&Ns=Pricing%7c0), you still will want to make sure whatever you pick can use the supply you're planning to use.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer. I do happen to have an NE5534 op amp with me. Can I use it to overcome these problems?

Comment: Read the datasheet.  It will tell you the minimum and maximum supply voltage

Comment: @C_Elegans - Also note that he's not using two batteries - just one. So no +/- 9.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast two 9v batteries will give you +/-9v.